# Unable to start socket server java

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to start a socket server by calling the class's default constructor, however server is not starting

Below is my server socket class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class TransactionServer
{
    public void TransactionServer() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Inside Create Server");
        Socket echoSocket;
        InputStream sin = null;
        OutputStream sout  = null;

        ObjectInputStream sinO=null;
        ObjectOutputStream soutO=null;

        try {
           ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(2000);
           System.out.println("Server Ruinning");
           echoSocket = s.accept();
           System.out.println("Connection from: " + echoSocket.getInetAddress());

           sinO = new ObjectInputStream(echoSocket.getInputStream());
           soutO = new ObjectOutputStream(echoSocket.getOutputStream());

           String temp = (String) sinO.readObject();
           System.out.println("" + temp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my invocation of object of this class:

```
public class TabbedPane extends JFrame {

    public TabbedPane() {

        TransactionServer newServer=new TransactionServer();
    }
}
```

However the server is not starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `newServer` instance doesn't call `TransactionServer()` !
so :

```
TransactionServer newServer=new TransactionServer();
                  newServer.TransactionServer();
```

Comment: Nice catch. What he thought was a constructor is actually a void method. +1

Answer (score 1):

You have used `void` when defining the `TransactionServer` constructor. Remove the `void`, and the constructor will be triggered, to run the socket server.

Replace line:

```
public void TransactionServer() throws IOException {
```

With:

```
public TransactionServer() throws IOException {
```

Other than this, I am assuming you have a main method somewhere to invoke the "invokation object". :-)